# Java convert 2 dimensional String array to String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to copy 2-dimensional String array to another 2-dimensional String array.Then convert the second  2-dimensional String array into string. After that print out the string
but the string does not show what is suppose to ...
I'm trying to do that without using the java library.

```
 public class Train {
//public static void main (String args){
public static void main(String[] args) {
String [][] ff = { {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},
                   {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},
                   {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},
                   {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},

                   {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},
                   {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},
                   {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},
                   {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"} };


    String[][] IP = new String[8][8];
    int x=0, y=0;
        for(int i = 1; i < 8; i +=2){

            for(int j = 7; j>=0 ; j--){
                y= 0;
            IP[x][y]=ff[j][i];
            System.out.print(IP[x][y]);
                    y++;               
            }
        if (i==7){
            i=-2;
            x++;
          }

        }
                String zz= "";
    for( int p = 0; p<8;p++){
        for( int q= 0 ; q< 8; q++){
        zz += IP[p][q];
       System.out.print(zz);
        }   
    }
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your question? Do yo get an error?

Comment: you're copying elements from ff[][] always to IP[0][0] (x, y are never changed).

Comment: I got this [[Ljava.lang.String;@134510ac

Comment: Thank you I edited my code and I have different problem. the string dont show what is suppose to

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `String yourString = Arrays.toString(yourArray);`

Comment: Thanks for your time but as i said i dont want to use the library

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(IP);
```

In Java, each object has [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method, the default is displaying the class name representation, then adding `@` and then the *hashcode*.

You should use [`Arrays#deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

`System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(yourArray));`

Comment: as i said i dont want to use the library. however, I tried that and it gives me some null values

Comment: You can iterate on the array, having two loops.

Comment: is not that what I did?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
System.out.print(IP);
```

is simply going to print out the Object representation.  You are almost there when you create a `zz` string.  Try printing that out after your iteration.

As you do not want to use any Java library you will need to iterate through the array again.  This is of course if you are assuming that `java.util.*` is a library.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the library:

```
String ffStr = "";
for (String[] sArray : ff) {
    for (String s : sArray) {
        ffStr += s;
    }
}
System.out.println(ffStr);
```

Comment: I appreciate ur help Simon. now, it prints out array ff fine; however, when I try to print out array IP, which copied array ff, it gives me null values for all values

Comment: Will you be wanting not to use methods contained in Arrays for this also?